# rails ignore rows that haven't got a 'true' value in the complete field AND has festival in the event_type field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tried to be specific with the title

This is what i have in my controller at the moment.

```
  def search
    @events = Event.search params[:search], suggest: true, misspellings: { distance: 1 }, order: { date: :asc, eventname: :asc }, match: :word_start
    if @events.results.any?
      render 'events/results'
    else
      render 'events/noresults'
    end
  end
```

Basically What i want to happen is if the row displayed has the event_type as festival and the complete field isn't true i don't what the result to be displayed.

Would this be done on the view or the controller? The view is just a basic each do

Thanks

Sam

Comment: So this action is invoked when the user visits `/events?search=<param>`? Also what is the connection between festivals and search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the search on an exclusive subset:

```
@events = Event.where("event_type != 'festival' AND complete=TRUE").search params[:search], suggest: true, misspellings: { distance: 1 }, order: { date: :asc, eventname: :asc }, match: :word_start
```

Comment: I think i may have messed the question up a tad, Would this only allow festivals that have complete as true. e.g. if the event_type was concert. and didn't have anything inside the true it'd show the concert?

Comment: No, this solution requires TRUE, you can do `complete!=FALSE` to include undefined complete states. Is you change it like this, you get all events that are not false and are not festivals. Isn't this what you asked? If you leave it as it is,  you get everything that is not festival, if complete is true.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you set up some methods on the event model which you can then use in a reject block.

```
if @events.results.reject {|event| event.festival? && event.incomplete?}.any?
  render 'events/results'
else
  render 'events/noresults'
end
```

in the events model you can define the 2 methods

```
def festival?
  event_type == 'festival'
end

def incomplete?
  !completed
end
```